# JS & ES6: Access static fields from within class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-next

In ES6, given the following example:

```
export default class MyStyle extends Stylesheet {
   static Color = {
      mainDark: '#000'
   }
   static Comp = {
      ...
      color: Color.mainDark
   }
}
```

How can I access Color.mainDark (the static field)?

Comment: You cannot. It's not defined until the closing `}` on the last line

Comment: in a method you could do `MyStyle.Color.mainDark`.

Comment: That's not ES6. That's some weird experimental (ES7-proposed) property intialisers.

Comment: sounds like either a duplicate of [es6 call static methods](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28627908/1048572)/[Call static method within a class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31116300/1048572) or [Self-references in object literal declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4616202/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi those are stage-1, so not that weird :-)

Comment: @zerkms: Weird in the sense that I really dislike the proposed operator(s). Apparently the choice of the "assignment operator" causes quite some confusion here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can access it as you would expect, however if I recall there were some issues when using Babel and exporting the class immediately, so export after defining the class *if* you're having problems:

```
class MyStyle extends Stylesheet {
   static Color = {
      mainDark: '#000'
   }

  someMethod() {
    console.log(MyStyle.Color.mainDark);
  }
}

export default MyStyle;
```

You can read more about the Babel issue in [an answer Marian made on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33620949/414062), which is supposedly fixed in Babel 6.2.1.

Comment: Is there something like `self.Color.mainDark` so that one can omit repeating the name of the class?

Comment: @Ionix I don't think so

Answer (score 1):

indeed, this.constructor points to the class hierarchy.

take a look:

```
class Some {
    static static_elem = 'elem';
    constructor(param) {
         
       console.log( Some.static_elem, param);
        console.log( this.constructor.static_elem, param);
    }
};

var some = new Some('some');

class SomeOther extends Some {
    constructor(param) {
        super(param);
        console.log( Some.static_elem, param);
        console.log( SomeOther.static_elem, param);
        console.log( this.constructor.static_elem, param);
    }
};

var someother = new SomeOther('someother');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'use strict';

 class User {
   constructor(firstName, lastName) {
   this.firstName = firstName;
   this.lastName = lastName;
 }

 static createGuest() {
    return new User("guest", "site");
   }
 };

 let user = User.createGuest();

  alert( user.firstName ); // guest

  alert( User.createGuest ); // createGuest ... (function)
```

And const:

```
'use strict';

class Menu {
 static get elemClass() {
   return "menu"
 }
}

alert( Menu.elemClass ); // menu
```

use call to context object --- this

[ES6 - Call static method within a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31116300/es6-call-static-method-within-a-class)